# How to rotated individual instance objects in geo nodes

Tags: untagged

I would like the skateboards to rotate as seen in the two images. However, I want them to rotate one after the other. In the image with the value, you can see that they all have the same rotation value. Here, I would like the second board to start rotating only when the first board has completed 10% of its 360-degree rotation. I have tried using GeoNodes, but I have not achieved the desired result.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image: Rotation shown]

[image: Rotation shonw 2]
[image: Geo Nodes]
[image: Value Rotation]

Answer (score 1):

with this node tree here:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you soooo much

Comment: you are welcome. If my answer helped you, pls click on the checkmark left of my answer. thx